how to implement graphql-query-complexity on nestjs with mercurius
I'm trying to implement maximum complexity for queries on a graphql API. Although, NestJs doesn't have documentation on how to do that with mercurius (only apollo).
https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/complexity
I've tried following this guide, but then I've got an error:
this.includeDirectiveDef = this.context.getSchema().getDirective('include');
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getDirective')

my code:
plugins: [
  {
    plugin: createComplexityRule({
      maximumComplexity: 2,
      variables: {},
      context: {},
      onComplete: (complexity: number) => {
        console.log('Determined query complexity: ', complexity);
      },
      createError: (max: number, actual: number) => {
        return new GraphQLError(
          `Query is too complex: ${actual}. Maximum allowed complexity: ${max}`,
        );
      },
      estimators: [
        simpleEstimator({
          defaultComplexity: 1,
        }),
      ],
    }),
    options: {},
  },
]


Mercurius is capable of complexity limiting by using validation rules, if cache is disabled.
The code for integrating with NestJS should be as follows:
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { GraphQLModule } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { MercuriusDriver, MercuriusDriverConfig } from '@nestjs/mercurius';
import queryComplexity, { simpleEstimator } from 'graphql-query-complexity';

export const GraphQLProvider =
  GraphQLModule.forRootAsync<MercuriusDriverConfig>({
    driver: MercuriusDriver,
    imports: [ConfigModule],
    inject: [ConfigService],
    useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => {
      return {
        cache: false,
        validationRules: ({ variables, operationName }) => [
          queryComplexity({
            maximumComplexity: 1,
            variables,
            operationName,
            estimators: [simpleEstimator({ defaultComplexity: 1 })],
            onComplete: () => {},
          }),
        ],
      };
    },
  });


For more information, read the docs:
https://github.com/slicknode/graphql-query-complexity
